# Pass array through void* and get the array back in python ctypes

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I'm wrapping a C Library using ctypes to make it available in Python (3). I'm a beginner in Python and ctypes.

One of the functions takes a `void*` pointing to an array as a parameter, and fills it. I think the data are integers but the documentation is pretty bad so I can't have confirmation. I might want to experiment with other types, but I tried with `c_int` here.

```
MY_API ULONG GetImage ( DWORD width, DWORD height, void * lpRawData);
```

I need to access the values stored in this array with Python.
So far, I've tried to configure the argtypes like so, but it fails.

```
from ctypes import windll, c_int, POINTER, byref
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, ULONG

# Height and Width are known
width = 47
height = 45

# Loading the Library
self._lib = windll.LoadLibrary('lib/myLib.dll')

# Building the reference to the C function
self.CGetImage = self._lib.GetImage
self.CGetImage.argtypes = (DWORD, DWORD, POINTER(c_int * (width*height)) )
self.CGetImage.restype = ULONG

# Creating the array storing the data
rawData = c_int * (width * height)

self.CGetImage( DWORD(width), DWORD(height), byref(rawData) )
```

which returns `byref argument must be a ctypes instance, not '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'`

Unfortunately, I'm a beginner and I couldn't really get far with what I found on the ctypes documentation of on the other SO posts, usually talking about `numpy` library. Usually in those posts, the types defined in the C API is also much more explicit than `void*`, and is usually found as a return value and not a parameter (though I guess it won't change much the way to work around this issue).

**How could I get those data back from my C library, in order to manipulate them as int or doubles with Python ?**

Comment: I don't know much about ctypes either, but can't you use `c_void_p`; you'll have to find a way to convert it to the appropriate data type later, but I guess initially you'd have to set up things with `c_void_p`.

Comment: Btw, are you missing an argtype in `.argtypes`. I.e., should it be `[DWORD, DWORD, c_void_p]` instead?

Comment: That's what I thought. But I have to find a way define the size of the array in the first place ! I would use `c_void_p` to store handles.

Comment: I think you only need to pass the void pointer in. How you work with the void pointer in Python is up to you. In Python, you will need to respect the idea of the width and height, and how you access, change, or cast the void pointer while is Python is up to you. However, `ctypes` only needs to know that it is a void pointer when interacting with the C code. C has no concept of what type or data a void pointer points to, so you do not need to express such ideas to `ctypes` when interacting with the C code. You only need to express those ideas when accessing or mutating the data in Python.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower So how could I retreive data that are stored in the array located by the `c_void_p` ?

Comment: Don't over-specify the pointer in `argtypes` to an array subclass; use a generic `int *`. The error itself is because you need to create an instance of the array type, i.e. `CGetImage.argtypes = (DWORD, DWORD, POINTER(c_int));` `rawData = (c_int * (width * height))();` `result = CGetImage(width, height, rawData)`.

Comment: @eryksun It seems to work alright. Though the library I'm wrapping has kind of an odd API so now I'm more struggling with understanding the data stored in the array than getting the data back. As far as this question is concerned you seem to have answer it! I will accept your answer if you write one. Cheers! :)